# How can I update the field if ID changes MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, dense-rank

Every month I receive files which I stacked them in the database with file date we received.

If the same ID has different memberid in the next month, then I should close that member in current month

For example below if my table

```
ID         membername     memberid      filedate     enddate
12345      Alpha          5678          2020-01-01
12345      Alpha          5678          2020-04-01
12345      Beta           9569          2020-05-01
12345      Gamma          8765          2020-08-01
```

As you see ID 12345 has same memeberid until 2020-05-01 then the memberid changed to 9569, now I need to update the enddate with one day before the most recent date (In this case it should be 2020-04-30).

```
ID         membername     memberid      filedate     enddate
12345      Alpha          5678          2020-01-01   2020-04-30
12345      Beta           9569          2020-05-01   2020-07-31
12345      Gamma          8765          2020-08-01   2999-12-31
```

Comment: I am struggling to find the way to solve

Answer (score 0):

Try the below using `lead()` window function if your db version is MySQL 8+

**[DEMO Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7622ca06253eae880d4b4fb3429a2242)**

```
select id,membername,memberid,filedate,
coalesce(date_sub(lead(filedate) over(order by filedate) , interval 1 day),'2999-12-31') as endate
from
(
select id,membername,memberid,min(filedate) as filedate
from t
group by id,membername,memberid
)A
```

OUTPUT:

```
id      membername  memberid    filedate    endate
12345   Alpha       5678        2020-01-01  2020-04-30
12345   Beta        9569        2020-05-01  2020-07-31
12345   Gamma       8765        2020-08-01  2999-12-31
```

Comment: @Chourey . . . This will not work if a name is repeated, but separated by other names.

Comment: What can I do in that case?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you want to ignore records where the previous name is the same.  Then you just want `lead()`:

```
select id, membername, filedate,
       lead(filedate, 1, '2999-12-31') over (partition by id order by filedate
from (select t.*,
             lag(membername) over (partition by id order by filedate) as prev_membername
      from t
     ) t
where prev_membername is null or prev_membername <> membername;
```

Very importantly, this will work if a member names is repeated -- but with other in between.